# Upstream QoS garanteed bandwidth

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, qos, h-qos

In the network I'm trying to manage there is a satellite link, the upstream of which is ~ 7 Mbps. In this upstream, I need to allocate 1.5 Mbps of guaranteed bandwidth for one single host, but nothing seems to work properly.

I'm testing upstream bandwidth with iperf3, and maximum avarage bit rate I could get with transmitting data is ~ 600 kbps.

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-132.38 sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-132.38 sec  9.82 MBytes   622 Kbits/sec                receiver
```

All traffic goes through the gi0 / 0.65 interface

[image]

Cisco IOS version

```
Cisco IOS Software, C2900 Software (C2900-UNIVERSALK9_NPE-M), Version 15.3(3)M3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
```

Policy settings

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.65
 encapsulation dot1Q 65
 ip address 10.200.23.254 255.255.255.252
 service-policy output gi0/0.65_return-channel
end


Policy Map gi0/0.65_return-channel
   Class class-default
     Average Rate Traffic Shaping
     cir 6500000 (bps)
     service-policy Only-host-fixed

Policy Map Only-host-fixed
   Class host-fixed
     priority 1500 (kbps) 9600


Class Map match-all host-fixed (id 1)
   Match access-group name host-fixed

Extended IP access list host-fixed
    10 permit ip host 10.200.23.244 any (40908 matches)
```

I tried explicit bandwidth command in class, tried bandwidth percent, it just does not work, so lastly I tried priority command.

Here quick picture to illustrate upstream bandwidth.

[image]

I am definitely missing something out about QoS configuration.

Comment: Is this TCP you are testing?

Comment: @RonMaupin yes, it's TCP

Comment: Can you actually achieve the ~7Mbit/s upstream through that path? Satellite links are usually high latency, and this increases the _bandwidth * delay product  (a.k.a. "bytes in flight")_ way beyond (unscaled) TCP receive windows of the end systems. Use https://www.switch.ch/network/tools/tcp_throughput/ or https://wintelguy.com/wanperf.pl to play with some numbers). Depending on host OS, you might have to make sure that iPerf makes the TCP receive window scale with  `-w <buffer size>`.  Alternatively: just send off UDP at the desired rate.

Comment: Also: Please remember that QoS only kicks in once a link/interface (or: your parent shaping class) gets saturated. If you'll want to see these 1.5Mbps guaranteed for that single host, you'll have to have other traffic actually saturating/oversubscribing that link.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi I will try out you suggestions. Yes, I knew that saturation of the link must be the case for QoS to start working. I thought that shape average in parent policy should account for that (I particularly made it below than average throughput on the graph). Also I tried bandwidth commnand on the interface, but after that I read that with parent - child policy it's not necessary.

Comment: Another tripwire to avoid: (depending on platform) _egress_ (in extenso: queuing) QoS class-maps/policy maps can not always match on the same set of criteria as _ingress_  class-maps/policy-maps do (without having checked: matching on tcp/udp ports with an ACL or on application using NBAR fall in this category). 
 
A safe strategy against this is to match and mark traffic upon  ingress into the device (by setting DSCP or IP Precence), and to just match on DSCP or Precedence for queuing/shaping on the egress side.

Comment: The latency will kill the TCP tests, and per @Marc'netztier'Luethi suggestion, remember that you mark traffic as close to the source as possible. We found that doing it all on the router really kills the router throughput.

Comment: So, I retested it with -P flag (parallel tcp streams) and with 3 and 4 tcp streams bw actually does allocate. So it might be bottleneck of single tcp stream over satellite link.

Comment: Yes multiple, parallel TCP streams (with unscaled TCP receive windows) can saturate what is called a "long fat pipe" (a link/path with a high _bandwitdh * delay_ product). If you can get the _receiving_ end to scale up its receive window size (use `-w <buffersize>`), you should be able to manage with a single stream. My apologies for not clearly stating that  both, but in particular the _receiver_ (iPerf: the "server") must scale up its receive window.